# Video and Audio player for AVI using Python and pipelines not working

Tags: python, audio, video, pipeline

I have been looking for the method to use avidemux, pipelines and python to display the video and audio from a single avi video file.  I can do it using gst-launch but i wanted to implement it in code.  Right now it sais that all the elements are created but it doens't access any of the dynamic alloction of pads from the avidemux or the decoder.

The entire code for python is below.

Thanks,

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import gobject, pygst
    pygst.require("0.10")
    import gst


    def allocate_muxer_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
        print "allocate prog entered"   

        if pad.get_caps()[0].to_string().startswith("a"):
            pad.link(audioqueue.get_pad("sink"))
            print 'audio Mux connected' 
        elif pad.get_caps()[0].to_string().startswith("v"):  
            pad.link(videoqueue.get_pad("sink"))    
            print 'Video Mux connected'

    def new_Adecode_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
        pad.link(audioconvert.get_pad("sink"))  
        print 'audio decode connected'

    def new_Vdecode_pad(dbin, pad, islast):  
        pad.link(videoconvert.get_pad("sink"))
        print 'video decode connected'

    pipeline = gst.Pipeline("PIPELINE")
    Bin = gst.Bin("pipeline")

    src = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "source")
    src.set_property("location", "testav.avi")

    demux = gst.element_factory_make("avidemux","avi-demuxer")
    audioqueue = gst.element_factory_make('queue', 'Audioqueue')
    videoqueue = gst.element_factory_make('queue','videoqueue')
    audiodecoder = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin2","Adecoder")
    videodecoder = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin2","Vdecoder")
    audioconverter = gst.element_factory_make("audioconvert","Audio_Converter") 
    videoconverter = gst.element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace","Video_Converter")
    audioSink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink","Sink_Audio")
    videoSink = gst.element_factory_make("ximagesink","Sink_Video")

    Bin.add(src)
    Bin.add_many(demux,audioqueue,videoqueue,audiodecoder,audioconverter,videodecoder,videoconverter,audioSink,videoSink)

    src.link(demux)
    gst.element_link_many(audioqueue,audiodecoder)
    gst.element_link_many(audioconverter,audioSink)
    gst.element_link_many(videoqueue,videodecoder)
    gst.element_link_many(videoconverter,videoSink)

    if (not(src) or not(demux) or not(audioqueue) or not(videoqueue) or not(videodecoder) or not(audiodecoder) or not(audioconverter) or not(videoconverter) or not(audioSink) or not(videoSink) ):
        print "Elements not Created"
    else:
        print "Elements Created"


    demux.connect("pad-added", allocate_muxer_pad)
    demux.connect("pad-added", allocate_muxer_pad)

    audiodecoder.connect("new-decoded-pad", new_Adecode_pad)
    videodecoder.connect("new-decoded-pad", new_Vdecode_pad)


    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    print "Pipeline Playing" 
    # enter into a mainloop
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()

    loop.run()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error logs? Or do `logging` to know what's going on actually. Some exceptions inside the site packages may die silently.

Comment: @Babu, No error logs appear, it just sits there and does not do anything (No audio, No video). But it sais that all elements are created properly so I am not sure whats wrong.